# Import Single Column CSV Files and join them into Single Three Column CSV File Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I should start by saying I'm no PowerShell expert at all, I can cobble stuff together OK but that's about it.

I have 3 .csv files that all contain 1 column of information.

I need a PowerShell script that will combine each column from the individual CSV files and combine them into a single 3 column CSV file.

i.e.

```
CSV1
Red
Green
Blue

CSV2
Monday
Tuesday

CSV3
Monkey
Badger
Tiger
Giraffe
```

And that combined would look like

```
CSV1    CSV2    CSV3
Red     Monday  Monkey
Green   Tuesday Badger
Blue            Tiger
                Giraffe
```

So far I have looked creating an object and adding members, but it seems that each member can only have one value.

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv "csv1.csv"
$csv2 = Import-Csv "csv2.csv"
$csv3 = Import-Csv "csv3.csv"

$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Rule Block 1" -Value $csv1[2] $csv1[3]
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Rule Block 2" -Value $csv2[2]
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Rule Block 3" -Value $csv3[2]
$obj | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\FJ Stuff\Powershell\exportTest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm not even sure if I'm  heading in the write direction with this.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear whether your single column CSV files contain headers (if not, to add a header use: `$csv1 = Import-Csv "csv1.csv" -Header CSV1`). Than you might use this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet: `$csv1 | FullJoin $csv2 | FullJoin $csv3`. See also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by using:

```
$file1 = @(gc "x")
$file2 = @(gc "y")
$file3 = @(gc "z")

$combined = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $file1.Count; $i++) {
    $combined += $file1[$i] + ', ' + $file2[$i] + ', ' + $file3[$i]
    }

$combined | Out-File "C:\test.csv" -encoding default
```

Simply replace the x/y/z with the locations of the CSV, this should combine them into the test csv and look like:

> title - title - title
>
> x - y - z
>
> x - y - z
>
> x - y - z
>
> x - y - z

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looking at that code, does it assume that all three files are the same length? If so I should have said that the files are unlikely to be the same length.

Comment: So I have managed to get it working using your code, thanks very much.